# How to make your app save automaticly?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an App in android studio. The only thing is that if you close the app you need to start over with the game. Do you guys know how i can integrate a autosave option in my app that every time the user closes the app and start it up again that they don't need to start over?

Comment: Do u know Android Lifecycle ?Do u heard about **savedInstateState** ?. i think you need to look into it.

Comment: have you read about the onClose()/onDestroy() event? You should take a look at that... maybe that's what you need!

Comment: I am kinda new to Android development. But thanks for the answer! @ULHASPATIL

Comment: you are welcome, look into it, you will find out lots of answers regarding that. just google it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Activity state on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onSavedInstanceState is used when recreating an activity due to things like orientation changes. check this link: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

If the user is exiting the application completely then you should look into persisting the data with a sqlite db or using shared preferences during the activity lifecycle, check this link: http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Android-Application-Activity-Lifecycle.jpg

When the user starts the app again then check the persisted data during onCreate()